# Java Encoding, Connection to Database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

I recently converted my latin1 database to utf8. all my collations and connection properties are set to utf8, also i´´m using &useUnicode for the mysql driver url.

The question is, as Java stores strings in utf16, do i need to do some conversion or does the driver convert it on the fly from utf16 to utf8 for the connection and the other way around?
i do ask in general but also for spring jdbc we currently use.

edit:
Lets say users type any type of string no matter what encoding it is into a swing JTextField. Java takes it, converts it to utf16 and stores it. if i told my jdbc driver that all data i will sent is already utf8 and it should not convert, how is that working out. 
Of course i did tests and it worked fine, but why?

Comment: Why don't you try it and tell us? :)

Comment: It's too good to last... so i better ask :)

Comment: java does not "store" strings in UTF-16, it manipulates the characters as Unicode, the internal representation is irrelevant, you tell it how you want to "store" them externally. You leave it up to the default that is your choice. Most people render them externally as UTF-8.

Comment: so getting a string from database over a utf8 connection would make rs.getString("Col") the same output as new String(rs.getString("Col").getBytes(),"utf8")?

Answer (score 0):

The conversion between utf16 and utf8 is a two-way street. So I don't think you need to do any conversion as long as you specify 'read this as utf8' in your java code whenever possible. If you read a raw string from database, you probably don't have to specify that at all, your driver/ORM should take take of that, when it detects the encoding from your db.